# Android accessibility cannot focus on custom view when android version more than 10

Tags: android, accessibility

I have a TestApp，which using canvas drawing a grid view. I create a testTouchHelper extends ExploreByTouchHelper. When I turn on talback on android device that OS version less than 10, the accessibility feature works fine, but when OS version more than 10, if I click a cell from grid view, the accessibility cannot focus on I selected cell, however it can read my contentDescripition.

This question has been bothering me for a long time.  Is there anyone who can help me with some ideas?  Thanks in advance.

My testTouchHelper it based on this example: https://github.com/xinguohenan/AndroidAccessibilityExample/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/xishui/example/ExploreByTouchHelperActivity.java

Comment: Have you tried just upgrading to the latest Android studio and using the latest API levels? I had to do that to run the code and then it seemed to work fine.